# How to include more than one (but not all) Perl test files in a test run?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, makefile

I am using ExtUtils::MakeMaker to manage one of my Perl libraries. The testing framework is setup the usual way with several test files in the `./t` directory.

If I want run *all* the tests in the `./t` directory, I run `make test`.

If I want to run the tests in a *single* file in the `./t` directory, I run `make TEST_FILES=./t/test01.t test`.

How do I run all the tests in *two* (or more) of the test files? I tried `make TEST_FILES=./t/test01.t,./t/test02.t test` but that does not work.

Comment: Would you be amenable to a solution like `make test01 test02`? Or maybe `make run_test01 run_test02`?

Answer (score 2):

Use spaces to separate files; use quotes to bind spaces to the `TEST_FILES` assignment.

```
make test TEST_FILES="t/test01.t t/test02.t"
```

If all of the tests have similar names, you can often specify them with shell wildcards, too

```
make test TEST_FILES=t/test0[12].t
```